# Form implementing WCF contract

Tags: c#, wcf

I need to the next thing:
I have one Form which gets the images from my cameras and show those images on the form.
Also I can choose on the Form which camera will be displayed in which image frame.
Now I want someone from remote computer to connect to my program and get some result based on current images.
So I used WCF. I wrote interface with [ServiceContract] attribute and method GetResult() with [OperationContract] attribute.
And I implemented that interface in my Form class, my Form now has method GetResult() which can be called from remote computer.
And when I start Service from main program like this

```
ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Form1), baseAddress);
```

my service will be available and remote user will be able to call GetResult() method but the Form1 with camera images wont be shown. I need it to be shown so I can choose which cameras to use. Is there any way to also start GUI of Form1 when starting service?

Answer (score 0):

Don't make your form the ServiceHost. It will just cause a big mess (threading issues, for one). Separate the two - have a form and a WCF host, and have the host notify the form of changes.

Comment: Yea I know it should be separeted, but is it possible to do that what I asked above, to start GUI along with service?

Comment: @AleksaStancetic - Why?  It's a *bad* idea.  Web services aren't designed to have a UI.  They're designed and intended to pass data to/receive data from the UI.

Comment: Is it possible then to have DataService object that gets Form as parameter in constructor and then call the methods from that form?